# How to create a line chart with date's on both axis?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart, timeserieschart

I need to implement a two date type axis with jasper-reports.

The time series chart allows a date on x-axis and a number value on y-axis, is there a way to implements two date type axis where both y-axis and x-axis is of date type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set y-axis as a Date axis you need to.

**1. Convert the Date in the `valueExpression` to a `java.lang.Number`**, since `valueExpression` does only allow this class (or a sub class)

Instead of passing a `java.util.Date` in the `valueExpression` pass the time in milliseconds `java.lang.Long` by calling [`Date.getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--)

```
<valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{myDateOnYAxis}.getTime()]]></valueExpression>
```

**2. Add a [`JRChartCustomizer`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRChartCustomizer.html) that changes the number axis to a date axis with relative formatter**

```
public class MyChartCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart jfchart, JRChart jrchart) {
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) jfchart.getPlot(); //get the plot

        //Create the new date axis for y
        DateAxis yDateAxis = new DateAxis();
        //Set desired time format
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM - yyyy"); 
        yDateAxis.setDateFormatOverride(dateFormat); 
        //Add your own Tickunit if you like (you can do with out also, comment out the below line and let JFreeChart decided)
        yDateAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.MONTH,3));

        //Set the new y-axis to the plot
        plot.setRangeAxis(yDateAxis);
    }
}
```

For how to add JRChartCustomizer to your design (jrxml) see [Sample reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/chartcustomizers/index.html)

## Result

[image: Resultl]

<sup>*Some random dates formatted in Italian</sup>

**Example jrxml used to generate graph with a csv datasource**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Test2DateGraph" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="2347c131-1884-430a-b77f-59f08f896c8a">
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Dates"/>
 <queryString language="csv">
  <![CDATA[]]>
 </queryString>
 <field name="Date1" class="java.util.Date"/>
 <field name="Date2" class="java.util.Date"/>
 <summary>
  <band height="353">
   <timeSeriesChart>
    <chart evaluationTime="Report" customizerClass="MyChartCustomizer">
     <reportElement x="10" y="50" width="530" height="256" uuid="4a93e72e-251b-4026-bb11-edc26ecd6599"/>
     <chartTitle/>
     <chartSubtitle/>
     <chartLegend/>
    </chart>
    <timeSeriesDataset>
     <timeSeries>
      <seriesExpression><![CDATA["SERIES 1"]]></seriesExpression>
      <timePeriodExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date2}]]></timePeriodExpression>
      <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date2}.getTime()]]></valueExpression>
     </timeSeries>
    </timeSeriesDataset>
    <timeSeriesPlot>
     <plot/>
     <timeAxisFormat>
      <axisFormat/>
     </timeAxisFormat>
     <valueAxisFormat>
      <axisFormat/>
     </valueAxisFormat>
    </timeSeriesPlot>
   </timeSeriesChart>
  </band>
 </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

> **Note**: If your not using a `timeSeriesChart`, the same needs to be done with x-axis.

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question, for some weird reason the y-axis shows as blank, no value, just blank.

Comment: @Martin no tick labels?, no graph? what is not displaying?, maybe your foreground color of the y-axis is just white?

Comment: @Martin I added the jrxml I used to test this and generate the above graph, see the "Show code snippet"

Comment: please see the screenshot of the chart [link](https://ibb.co/dgi8DF) for some reason it won't display the x-axis values

Comment: please checkout out this chart screenshot of what i got using your code https://ibb.co/nRiB0v

Comment: @Martin nice, maybe you need another TickUnit then I (1 tick every 3 months, on your chart it seems that you need to tick more often), or just remove that code and let jfreechart decide

Comment: brilliant removing the TickUnit did the job. here is a screenshot using a linechart and also works using the timeseries https://ibb.co/nytrYF .  Much appreciated